# Working with Excel sheets in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I need to import some Excel files in MATLAB and work on them. My problem is that each Excel file has 15 sheets and I don't know how to "number" each sheet so that I can make a loop or something similar (because I need to find the average on a certain column on each sheet).

I have already tried importing the data and building a loop but MATLAB registers the sheets as chars.

Comment: What have you tired so far? Can you post it?

Comment: I've tried importing the data (using variable= impordata(filename) and i got a struct containing all the sheets etc. I couldn't find a way to call each sheet in a loop because the sheets were imported with their names and not as numbers (say "sheet1, sheet2 etc). )

Comment: Ok, i ll re-edit the post then. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I did that. Sorry for any inconvenience I might have caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've just remembered that i posted this question almost 2 years ago, and since I figured it out, I thought that posting the answer could prove useful to someone in the future. 
So to recap; I needed to  import a single column from  4 excel files, with each file containing 15 worksheets. The columns were of variable lengths. I figured out two ways to do this. The first one is by using the xlsread function with the following syntax.

```
for count_p = 1:2
    a = sprintf('control_group_%d.xls',count_p);
    [status,sheets,xlFormat] = xlsfinfo(a);

    for sheetindex=1:numel(sheets)
        [num,txt,raw]=xlsread(a,sheets{sheetindex},'','basic');
        data{sheetindex}=num;
        FifthCol{count_p,sheetindex} = (data{sheetindex}(:,5));

    end
end


  for count_p = 3:4
    a = sprintf('exercise_group_%d.xls',(count_p-2));
    [status,sheets,xlFormat] = xlsfinfo(a);

    for sheetindex=1:numel(sheets)
        [num,txt,raw]=xlsread(a,sheets{sheetindex},'','basic');
        data{sheetindex}=num;
        FifthCol{count_p,sheetindex} = (data{sheetindex}(:,5));
    end
end
```

The files where obviously named control_group_1, control_group_2 etc. I used the 'basic' input in xlsread, because I only needed the raw data from the files, and it proved to be much faster than using the full functionality of the function.

The second way to import the data, and the one that i ended up using, is building your own activeX server and running a single excelapplication on it. Xlsread "opens" and "closes" an activeX server each time it's called so it's rather time consuming (using the 'basic' input does not though). The code i used is the following.

```
 Folder=cd(pwd); %getting the working directory
d = dir('*.xls'); %finding the xls files
N_File=numel(d);  % Number of files

hexcel = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %starting the activeX server
                                           %and running an Excel
                                           %Application on it
hexcel.DisplayAlerts = true;

for index = 1:N_File  %Looping through the workbooks(xls files)

    Wrkbk = hexcel.Workbooks.Open(fullfile(pwd, d(index).name)); %VBA 
                                                                 %functions                                    
    WorkName = Wrkbk.Name;  %getting the workbook name           %&commands
    display(WorkName)
    Sheets=Wrkbk.Sheets;    %sheets handle
    ShCo(index)=Wrkbk.Sheets.Count; %counting them for use in the next loop
    for j = 1:ShCo(index) %looping through each sheet

        itemm = hexcel.Sheets.Item(sprintf('sheet%d',j)); %VBA commands
        itemm.Activate;
        robj = itemm.Columns.End(4); %getting the column i needed

        numrows = robj.row;          %counting to the end of the column
        dat_range = ['E1:E' num2str(numrows)]; %data range
        rngObj = hexcel.Range(dat_range);
        xldat{index, j} = cell2mat(rngObj.Value); %getting the data in a cell
    end;
end
%invoke(hexcel);
Quit(hexcel);
delete(hexcel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `xlsinfo` to get the sheet names, then use `xlsread` in a loop.

```
[status,sheets,xlFormat] = xlsfinfo(filename);
for sheetindex=1:numel(sheets)
    [num,txt,raw]=xlsread(filename,sheets{sheetindex});
    data{sheetindex}=num; %keep for example the numeric data to process it later outside the loop.
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It really helped me to import each sheet and number them, but i still got the problem that i do not know how to call a specific column of the data variable. I actually need to find the average (and store in a different table) of a certain column on each sheet. So when i use a loop like : for i=1:15 a(i)=data{1, i}  i get an error (In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.) Sorry if i m wasting your time on silly things but i've been stuck for a while :p Thanks again.

Comment: It seems `a` is an array. Elements of an array are scalars (single numbers), you have to use a cell array instead.